# Why do I keep getting an error when trying to import my file?

Tags: r, rnotebook

I'm trying to read csv file using R notebook and keep getting this error:

```
Error: 'Examples/data/starbucks.csv' does not exist in current 
working directory ('C:/Users/c227466/Desktop')
```

I'm not sure what's going on!
This is the code I used:

```
starbucks <- read_csv("Examples/data/starbucks.csv")
starbucks
```

Comment: The error is telling you that there is no folder called "Examples" in folder "Desktop" try `read_csv(file.choose())` to look through your folders to find the folder called "Examples" and the file called "starbucks.csv".

Answer (score 0):

Your working directory is your desktop (which is not recommended). On your desktop, you should add a folder "Examples" and, in it, another folder "data" and your file there.